# Magento seasonal theme schedule?

Tags: php, css, magento

I have setup our Magento (1.5) store with the default theme and a few seasonal/event based alternate stylesheets. Simple changes (such as the background image) etc..

I would like to be able to set the theme to change on a calendar basis. So, for example, at midnight on the 10th December the theme would change to the Christmas variation and then at midnight on the 28th December it would change to the New Year theme.

I am *almost* certain that I have seen somewhere the ability to set a custom design along with a date it should be enabled. Although, I could be thinking of the individual category designs?

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for custom programming on this one.  Just navigate to

```
System -> Design
```

and add a design change.

Comment: Do you know if this can be used for only css changes?

Comment: Yes.  CSS files are stored in a skin folder, and that skin folder's name is based on the current theme/design name that's set.